# Trouble using INNER JOIN in SQLite in Android

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have a MySQL database at a local server. I fetch the data from the MySQL database using PHP and JSON over HTTP. In the Android app, an SQLite database is populated using the JSON result. I have verified that the SQLite database is actually populated by running test queries similar to

```
Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery("SELECT recipe_id, ingredient_id, name FROM mm_ingredient_in_recipe_groups", null);
```

and then iterating the resulting cursor to see that the data is present. The data that is present is stored in three tables:

1. `mm_ingredients`, containing ingredients for recipes.
2. `mm_recipes`, containing data for recipes.
3. `mm_ingredient_in_recipe`, containing data for joining the data in `mm_recipes` and `mm_ingredients` (i.e. resolving the many-to-many relationship).

What I want to do is to run a query that selects ingredients for an argument recipe name. This means that I have to INNER JOIN `mm_ingredients` with `mm_ingredient_in_recipe` and also with `mm_recipes`.

I have tried running the following query:

```
database.rawQuery("SELECT ingredient.name, ingredient.base_unit FROM mm_ingredients AS ingredient INNER JOIN mm_ingredient_in_recipe AS ir ON ir.ingredient_id = ingredient._id INNER JOIN mm_recipes AS recipe ON ir.recipe_id = recipe._id WHERE recipe.name = ?", new String[] {"Spicy tomatsuppe"});
```

This returns an empty cursor. In my MySQL database, however, running the corresponding query

```
SELECT ingredient.name, ingredient.base_unit FROM mm_ingredients AS ingredient INNER JOIN mm_ingredient_in_recipe AS ir ON ir.ingredient_id = ingredient.id INNER JOIN mm_recipes AS recipe ON ir.recipe_id = recipe.id WHERE recipe.name = "Spicy tomatsuppe";
```

returns the expected data. What am I doing wrong here? It seems like every query I run works fine up to the point where I start including INNER JOINs. (The id fields are named _id in SQLite, as should be best practice as far as I know.)

**Edit: add code for writing to database:**

Below is an example of how I populate the database for the table `mm_recipes`. It is similar for the two other tables. I use `JSONArray.optString()` for SQLite's `TEXT` data type, `JSONArray.optInt()` for `INTEGER` and `JSONArray.optDouble()` for `REAL`.

```
public static final String TABLE_NAME                       = "mm_recipes";
public static final String TABLE_NAME_IN_JSON               = "mm_recipes";

public static final String COLUMN_ID                        = "_id";
public static final String COLUMN_NAME                      = "name";
public static final String COLUMN_IN_APP                    = "in_app";
public static final String COLUMN_DIFFICULTY                = "difficulty";
public static final String COLUMN_TIME_CONSUMPTION_UPPER    = "time_consumption_upper";
public static final String COLUMN_TIME_CONSUMPTION_LOWER    = "time_consumption_lower";
public static final String COLUMN_PREPARATION_TIME          = "preparation_time";
public static final String COLUMN_PORTIONS                  = "portions";
public static final String COLUMN_PORTIONS_UNIT             = "portions_unit";
public static final String COLUMN_DESCRIPTION               = "description";
public static final String COLUMN_TIPS                      = "tips";
public static final String COLUMN_USE_INGREDIENT_GROUPS     = "use_ingredient_groups";

public static final void populateDatabase(SQLiteDatabase database, JSONObject databaseData) throws JSONException{

    JSONArray table_data = databaseData.optJSONArray(TABLE_NAME_IN_JSON);
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();

    for (int i = 0; i < table_data.length(); i++){
        JSONObject data = table_data.getJSONObject(i);

        contentValues.clear();

        contentValues.put(COLUMN_NAME,                      data.optString(COLUMN_NAME));
        contentValues.put(COLUMN_IN_APP,                    data.optInt(COLUMN_IN_APP));
        contentValues.put(COLUMN_DIFFICULTY,                data.optString(COLUMN_DIFFICULTY));
        contentValues.put(COLUMN_TIME_CONSUMPTION_UPPER,    data.optInt(COLUMN_TIME_CONSUMPTION_UPPER));
        contentValues.put(COLUMN_TIME_CONSUMPTION_LOWER,    data.optInt(COLUMN_TIME_CONSUMPTION_LOWER));
        contentValues.put(COLUMN_PREPARATION_TIME,          data.optInt(COLUMN_PREPARATION_TIME));
        contentValues.put(COLUMN_PORTIONS,                  data.optInt(COLUMN_PORTIONS));
        contentValues.put(COLUMN_PORTIONS_UNIT,             data.optString(COLUMN_PORTIONS_UNIT));
        contentValues.put(COLUMN_DESCRIPTION,               data.optString(COLUMN_DESCRIPTION));
        contentValues.put(COLUMN_TIPS,                      data.optString(COLUMN_TIPS));
        contentValues.put(COLUMN_USE_INGREDIENT_GROUPS,     data.optInt(COLUMN_USE_INGREDIENT_GROUPS));

        database.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);
    }

}
```

For reference, here is also an example of how the `mm_recipe` table is created. In my class for `mm_recipe`:

```
public static final String DATATYPE_ID                      = "INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL";
public static final String DATATYPE_NAME                    = "TEXT NOT NULL";
public static final String DATATYPE_IN_APP                  = "INTEGER DEFAULT 0";
public static final String DATATYPE_DIFFICULTY              = "TEXT NOT NULL";
public static final String DATATYPE_TIME_CONSUMPTION_UPPER  = "INTEGER NOT NULL";
public static final String DATATYPE_TIME_CONSUMPTION_LOWER  = "INTEGER NOT NULL";
public static final String DATATYPE_PREPARATION_TIME        = "INTEGER";
public static final String DATATYPE_PORTIONS                = "INTEGER NOT NULL";
public static final String DATATYPE_PORTIONS_UNIT           = "TEXT NOT NULL";
public static final String DATATYPE_DESCRIPTION             = "TEXT";
public static final String DATATYPE_TIPS                    = "TEXT";
public static final String DATATYPE_USE_INGREDIENT_GROUPS   = "INT";

/**Create table statement.*/
public static final String CREATE_TABLE = 
    "CREATE TABLE"                  + " " + TABLE_NAME                      + " (" +
    COLUMN_ID                       + " " + DATATYPE_ID                     + ", " +
    COLUMN_NAME                     + " " + DATATYPE_NAME                   + ", " +
    COLUMN_IN_APP                   + " " + DATATYPE_IN_APP                 + ", " +
    COLUMN_DIFFICULTY               + " " + DATATYPE_DIFFICULTY             + ", " +
    COLUMN_TIME_CONSUMPTION_UPPER   + " " + DATATYPE_TIME_CONSUMPTION_UPPER + ", " +
    COLUMN_TIME_CONSUMPTION_LOWER   + " " + DATATYPE_TIME_CONSUMPTION_LOWER + ", " +
    COLUMN_PREPARATION_TIME         + " " + DATATYPE_PREPARATION_TIME       + ", " +
    COLUMN_PORTIONS                 + " " + DATATYPE_PORTIONS               + ", " +
    COLUMN_PORTIONS_UNIT            + " " + DATATYPE_PORTIONS_UNIT          + ", " +
    COLUMN_DESCRIPTION              + " " + DATATYPE_DESCRIPTION            + ", " +
    COLUMN_TIPS                     + " " + DATATYPE_TIPS                   + ", " +
    COLUMN_USE_INGREDIENT_GROUPS    + " " + DATATYPE_USE_INGREDIENT_GROUPS  + ");";
```

In my `SQLiteOpenHelper` class:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database) {
    database.execSQL(Table_mm_recipes.CREATE_TABLE);
    database.execSQL(Table_mm_ingredient_in_recipe.CREATE_TABLE);
    database.execSQL(Table_mm_ingredients.CREATE_TABLE);
}
```

Comment: You are probably using wrong data types when writing the data to the DB. Show that code.

Comment: I use `JSONArray`'s `optString()`, `optInt()` and `optDouble()` methods to get the data from JSON. These should correspond to `SQLite`'s `TEXT`, `INTEGER` and `REAL` if I am not mistaken. I edited the question to include an example of how I populate the database for `mm_recipes`. It is done in the same way for the two other tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be (as expected) some silly mistake. I'll just leave this here in case others do similar mistakes.

Since I had set up the code to delete everything on the database on creation each time, in this manner:

```
database.execSQL("DELETE FROM " + Table_mm_recipes.TABLE_NAME);
database.execSQL("DELETE FROM " + Table_mm_ingredient_in_recipe.TABLE_NAME);
database.execSQL("DELETE FROM " + Table_mm_ingredients.TABLE_NAME);
```

something bad happened to the data somehow. Doing this does not really make sense, since you can just create the database and insert data at `SQLiteOpenHelper.onCreate()` and be fine. Just uninstall and reinstall the app if you need to update the data before any versioning is set up. Then you may destroy the data at `SQLiteOpenHelper.onUpgrade()` if preferred. I am not sure *how* the data were messed up, but they surely were.

What *is* strange though, is that I could still see that the database had data in it by doing a simple

```
Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery("SELECT recipe_id, ingredient_id, name FROM mm_ingredient_in_recipe_groups", null);
```

and iterating that cursor from before. I did this for all tables directly before the `INNER JOIN` statements, but they still did not work. It has probably something to do with the erroneous deletion/creation of the database.

Other than that, all the code above should be valid and working.